# Google Sheets, query, select by month

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, select, google-query-language

I'm trying to select data by month but the behavior of the query/select is not what I expect. Here's a simplified sheet:

[image]

The month column just uses month() on column A and produces what I'd expect 1, 2, 3, 4

But the query in column D behaves as if the months are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

months in QUERY actually starts from 0 so your formula should be:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select B where month(A)+1 = 1", )
```

or:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select B where month(A) = 0", )
```

for getting January

documentation:

[image]

Comment: So month() in a query returns zero-based but the standalone month() returns 1-based. Wow!  Thanks :-)